# No association bonus?

Tags: bug, stackexchange, reputation

Does the Latin Stack Exchange not give an association bonus for having a high reputation on other SE sites?  I'm not particularly concerned on a personal level, but I do wonder if that's intentional or if it's a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The Latin site is no different, and you should receive your bonus as usual.
As far as I know, this happens occasionally across the network.
[A similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308984/321340) was recently asked on the main meta, and **the solution is to delete your Latin account and rejoin this community**.
If you lose access to your question after deleting your Latin account, I hope we are able to merge the old account with the new one.

Let me know if you encounter any problems, and I will try to find a solution.